# Does YUI Combine multiple JS files in a specified order?

Tags: javascript, yui

If so, what is the usage? I am trying this:

```
-jar yuicompressor-2.4.7 file1.js, file2.js -o combined.js
```

but I get an error that the 'type' option should be specified.

If I do the same with 1 file, it is minified and the contents are output to `stdout`. I would like to combine `file1` and `file2` in that order.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comma after `file1.js`?

Comment: You cannot combine files by using commas.

Answer (score 1):

If it complains that the type option should be specified, you should specify it, like this:

```
-jar yuicompressor-2.4.7 file1.js, file2.js --type js -o combined.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the YUI Compressor combines files. You can use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to automate the task of minifying and combining. If you're new to Ant and making build processes, this should be a good introduction: http://addyosmani.com/blog/client-side-build-process/

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I just ran into this problem (or something similar). I believe the answer is that the @Nick's command syntax is incorrect for specifying multiple files. I think YUI Compessor *does* support processing multiple files *but* it only has one input file parameter, so you must use wildcards. IOW, this works:

```
...yui-compressor.jar -o blah.css *.css
```

This doesn't:

```
...yui-compressor.jar -o blah.css 1.css 2.css
```

At least this is my experience. One should be able to concatenate all the files together some other way and pipe them into the command though. For example, on Windows:

```
type 1.css 2.css | java -jar yui-compressor.jar --type js -o blah.css
```

Or on Unix/Linux:

```
cat 1.css 2.css | java -jar yui-compressor.jar --type js -o blah.css
```

(or you could probably use file redirection)

Make sure you `cat` or `type` the files in the desired order.